# building a string

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="./user.cvs"

while IFS=';' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12 f13
do

  path="./QRcodes/$f2$f3.png"

  vcard="BEGIN:VCARD%0AN;CHARSET=utf-8:$f3;$f2;;$f1;%0AADR;CHARSET=utf-8;INTL;PARCEL;WORK:;;$f10;$f11;;$f12;$f13%0AEMAIL;INTERNET:$f6%0AORG:$f4%0ATEL;WORK:$f8%0ATEL;FAX;WORK:$f9%0ATITLE:$f5%0AURL;WORK:$f7%0AEND:VCARD"

  latex=""

  encodedVCard=$(echo "$vcard" | sed -e 's/\+/\%2B/g')

  url="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=300x300&data=$encodedVCard"

  wget -O "$path" "$url"

  latex+="\n \\begin{tabular}{ C C } \\includegraphics[height=30mm]{graphic.png} & Name \\\\ \\end{tabular}"

  echo $latex

done < "$input"
```

Everything works except the 'echo $latex' always prints the same line instead of multiple times. What am I missing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to append to a string, just

```
latex="$latex newstring"
```

or

```
latex=${latex}newstring
```

You need to be careful that bash doesn't interpret the above as a new var e.g. `"$a4`" would be interpreted as a variable `a4` and not as `$a` with `4` appended.

Comment: ok, then this should work: `latex="$latex a" echo $latex` but It always shows only one a

Comment: You're resetting 'latex' in each loop iteration

Comment: @Brian Agnew I wish I'd said that. Oh, yeah, I did.

Comment: so another question: `if ["${counter:-0}" -gt 21] ;` is there an error in this statement?

Comment: @HotPizzaBox - I would raise another question. My bash knowledge isn't that great

Comment: @Barmar - you did indeed say that

Comment: var+=string works fine in bash (going back to v 3.2, at least). The problem is with the inclusion and handling of embedded newlines.

Comment: You need a space before the closing square bracket.

Comment: @Chepner - thx for that. Turns out I had an old copy of bash to run against. Now amended

Answer (score 4):

Several problems:

1. Backslash expressions are not treated specially inside double quotes, so "\n"
    is two characters, "\" and "n", not a single newline. Use $'\n' to include an actual
    newline
2. `echo $latex` expands the variable, but bash performs wordsplitting on any whitespace contained in `latex`, including newlines, so the newlines are never seen by `echo`. You need to quote the variable: `echo "$latex"`.
3. As pointed out by others, you are resetting the variable in each iteration of the loop.

Putting it all together,

```
input="./user.cvs"
latex=""

while IFS=';' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12 f13
do

  path="./QRcodes/$f2$f3.png"

  vcard="BEGIN:VCARD%0AN;CHARSET=utf-8:$f3;$f2;;$f1;%0AADR;CHARSET=utf-8;INTL;PARCEL;WORK:;;$f10;$f11;;$f12;$f13%0AEMAIL;INTERNET:$f6%0AORG:$f4%0ATEL;WORK:$f8%0ATEL;FAX;WORK:$f9%0ATITLE:$f5%0AURL;WORK:$f7%0AEND:VCARD"

  #encodedVCard=$(echo "$vcard" | sed -e 's/\+/\%2B/g')
  # You can use bash parameter expansion instead of piping into sed 
  encodedVCard="${vcard//+/%2B}"

  url="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=300x300&data=$encodedVCard"
  wget -O "$path" "$url"
  latex+=$'\n \\begin{tabular}{ C C } \\includegraphics[height=30mm]{graphic.png} & Name \\\\ \\end{tabular}'

  echo "$latex"

done < "$input"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
latex=""
```

in the loop, so it resets it each time. Put that before the beginning of the loop.